# SharePoint Calendar Validation for 15 Minute Meetings

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-calendar, validation-list-items

I'm trying to setup a SharePoint Online Calendar to only allow users to setup appointments in 15 minute increments starting at the top of the our.

For example, 8:00 to 8:15, 8:15 to 8:30 and so on. I'm pretty bad at this stuff, but came up with the formula below that I entered in the Validation Settings. It mostly works, but does not allow me to schedule meetings from the 45 minute mark to the top of the hour (8:45 to 9:00) doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?  I don't have access to do anything crazy and have to stick with out of the box features.

```
=AND(MINUTE([End Time])-MINUTE([Start Time])=15,OR(MINUTE([Start Time])=0,MINUTE([Start Time])=15,MINUTE([Start Time])=30,MINUTE([Start Time])=45))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follwoing steps:

1.Create a Calculated column named "**Mins**" in the list

2.Set Column Formula:

```
=INT(([End Time]-[Start Time])*1440)
```

[image]

3.Set Validation Formula:

```
=[Mins]=14
```

[image]

[image]